# CILanczosScaleTransform filter yields GL_INVALID_VALUE

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0, core-image

In my photo editing iOS app I want to scale down large images before sending them into my filter pipeline. I'm using the [CILanczosScaleTransform filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CILanczosScaleTransform) of Apple's Core Image framework for that.

Now for some images I get a black screen in the result. I enabled the "OpenGL ES Error" breakpoint in Xcode and found that a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error is thrown **inside** Core Image—when it's trying to create an intermediate texture for the Lanczos filter, to be precise.

After countless experiments I found that it only happens if the **resulting image** would have a width **greater then 2048 pixels**.
So for example images taken with the build-in camera in landscape mode scaled down to 4 MP (2369x1769) cause this error. Portrait images of the same size (height > 2048) work without problems.

If I'm using the [CIAffineTransform filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAffineTransform) instead I'm not getting that error. But I'd prefer to use Lanczos since it yields better results.

I tested on an iPad Mini (non-retina, iOS 7.1) and an iPhone 5s (iOS 7.0.6) with the same result.

Any ideas on what is causing this issue? I searched online but was not able to find any documented or non-documented restrictions concerning image sizes for this filter.

Comment: Post your code please and verify the aspect ration is not greater than 1. I just solved my black screen issue and may be able to help.